# Which part of speech is "back" in “then she went back to her secretaire”?

Tags: grammar

Which part of speech is "back" in the sentence “then she went back to her secretaire”?

Comment: What has your research told you? [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/back) | [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/back_1) | [Lexico/Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/back). Hint: the word describes a verb (*went*)

Comment: Traditional grammar calls it an adverb, but modern grammar calls it a preposition.

Comment: @AndrewLeach [But we shouldn't use dictionaries for grammatical information, especially parts of speech!](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635)

Comment: @araucaria That doesn't stop a bit of research saying "I found this... but ..."

Comment: @BillJ, preposition? positioned in front of what? the noun to?

Comment: @Toothrot Prepositions take all kinds of complements, not just NPs. And sometimes no complements at all! Most dictionaries still get this wrong, but here's one that gets it right: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/back).

Comment: @Araucaria. I agree that dictionaries cannot necessarily be relied on for grammatical information. However, descriptive grammars do not all agree on classification and terminology either, prompting the question: _Which one should I use_? But there are other issues: 1. Most dictionaries are online; descriptive grammars such as CGEL are not. 2. It is much more difficult to find information about individual words in descriptive grammars, assuming that the information exists at all.

Comment: @Shoe Actually, many grammars such as CamGEL etc have a lexical index, so it's actually very easy to look them up. However, my point here is that it's no use batting users over the head with "Why didn't you look it up in a dictionary?", when dictionaries are not a good starting point in the first place - which is why I feel it should be ok to ask here, because - as you say - it's not *so* easy to find good reference grammars on the web.

Comment: @Shoe FWIW, you can [check out *back* here, p144 example 37 in ASIEG](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwinopeQgvDiAhUytHEKHT9xCbUQFjACegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FSimhachalam_Thamarana%2Fpost%2FWhat_is_the_best_book_for_learning_of_English_language%2Fattachment%2F59d624a879197b8077982f98%2FAS%253A314223010222080%25401451928011724%2Fdownload%2FA%2BStudent%2527s%2BIntroduction%2Bto%2BEnglish%2BGrammar.pdf&usg=AOvVaw23OFd4AIhJI7tn2WO3FRyf)

Comment: @Araucaria. Thanks for the link to the book. I have the paper edition, which I think is very good, but it's always useful to have a digital version.

Comment: @Araucaria. As to the other issue, dictionaries have hundreds of thousands of words as opposed to the hundreds of words in the lexical indexes of grammar books. So learners are always going to quickly find their word in dictionary and in most cases the part of speech will be accurate. A grammar book such as the CGEL has, for example, over 20 pages or page ranges for the word _both_. That requires a lot of searching and reading to determine its part of speech in the context the learner is asking about.

Comment: @Araucaria. Finally, a question from English teacher to English teacher. What consequence does it have for the learner to be told that _back_ is actually a preposition, not an adverb as her dictionary tells her?

Comment: @Shoe Well, where to begin really. The fact is that the confusion  between adverbs and prepositions causes so many problems that the horrible knock on effects for students is quite pervasive. Take for example, a problem which I'm sure you've come across with sentences like "I don't like here" or "There is very hot" (For "I don't like it here", or "It is very hot there"). Or how about "His speech is too quickly" versus "He is back" (Here you've got the problem of using an adverb as a complement of non-specifying *BE*, whereas you can freely use prepositions as shown by *back*.

Comment: @Shoe There's also the fact that we never teach students that the main intensifying modifiers of spacial and temporal prepositions in English are *straight* and *right* - so something they underuse. This contrasts with the fact that *very* is the typical modifier of adverbs --> *Put it very back here* versus *Walk very far*. Etc, etc .... There's also the fact that we use noun measure phrases regularly to modify prepositions, but not adverbs: *three miles away* but not *two months recently* and so on. There's lots, lots more.

Comment: @Araucaria. In my ESL setting discussions about what part of speech a word is are rare. Students are comfortable with the concept of usage, which I refer to as single word grammar. So they are satisfied with the explanation that, for example, _here_ cannot function as a subject or object. Part of speech classification adds no value.

Comment: @Araucaria. In any case, there is always the danger of circularity. Student: _What part of speech is 'back'?_ Teacher: _It's a preposition_. Student: _How do I know it's a preposition?_ Teacher: _Because you can't say 'He's very back'. Student: _How do I know you can't say 'He's very back'?_ Teacher: _Because 'back' is  a preposition_ Ok, I'm signing off here, but it would be nice to pursue this in chat when I have more time than now.

Comment: @BillJ, sounds odd. A preposition is something that is positioned in front of something, so it must have a ''complement''.  Or will you tell me this is falling victim to the ''etymological fallacy''?